# Calculate z-score in bootstrap

Tags: r, bootstrap

In my literature book I found that the z-score can be calculated by the following function:

z = (data point - mean) / standard deviation

Now I'm reading on bootstrap and I found that they calculated the z-score using the outcome of the boostrap analysis by the following R code:

$tm$ is a vector holding the difference in response times between two groups.

$diff.mean = function(x,i)$  $mean(x[i])$

$boot(tm,diff.mean,R=20000)$
$$
z = tm.boot$t0/sd(tm.boot$t)
$$
Can someone explain why the mean is not used in this formula? Is it because the mean is 0? If so, why is the mean 0?

Comment: If you don’t provide more context, it will be difficult to answer... what is bootstrapped?

Comment: I run the bootstrap equivalent to a paired t-test by using a vector which holds the difference of two vectors. I'm bootstrapping to find a difference between two groups in terms of the mean.

Comment: Doesn’t the *paired $t$-test* bit explain why $0$ is taken as the expected value? In fact your bootstrap is used only to estimate a standard deviation.

Comment: So the mean is 0 as the expected difference between the two groups are 0?

Comment: yes it looks like it's because it's testing against 0 (it's like they're doing [score-0]/SE, where SE is the standard error)